# Can you pass a function as a message in Elixir/Erlang?

Tags: elixir

It is said that functions are first class citizens in Elixir/Erlang. Can functions be passed as messages?

While exploring the Elixir API, I came across `Agent#get_and_update(agent, fun, timeout \\ 5000)`. I imagine get and update operation is atomic. The only way I think this is possible is if the `fun` is run on agent process rather than the client process that interacts with the Agent.

If `fun` is run on the client process, it opens up to a lot of questions about guaranteeing atomicity and client process failure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can.

from the [agent docs for `get_and_update/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Agent.html#get_and_update/3).

> The function `fun` is sent to the `agent` which invokes the function passing the agent state.

The agent process itself runs the function, updating its state atomically.

Under the hood, Agents are just a specialized `GenServer`. So if we look at the code for [`get_and_update/3`](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/master/lib/elixir/lib/agent.ex#L274-L277), we can see that we are actually just passing the function to a `GenServer` to run.

```
@spec get_and_update(agent, (state -> {a, state}), timeout) :: a when a: var
def get_and_update(agent, fun, timeout \\ 5000) when is_function(fun, 1) do
  GenServer.call(agent, {:get_and_update, fun}, timeout)
end
```

Comment: Never realized Elixir documentation was so thorough! Next time I'll RTFM.